# how to import geopandas in google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, geopandas

```
!apt install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal
!apt install python3-rtree 
!pip install git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git
!pip install descartes
```

I get a warning from line 4 onwards. Also, after running this code, if I run the "import geopandas as gpd" code, it throws an error and the import is not possible.

I've searched several things, but I'm not sure where the error is coming from. I need help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I replicate your situation on my colab and this line of code caused a problem

```
!pip install git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git
```

and rest of line of code working properly.

```
!apt install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal 
!apt install python3-rtree 
!pip install git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git # cause problem
!pip install descartes
```

Now if you want to work with geopandas and import geopandas in your colab then follow this step. It work on my machine.

```
!pip install geopandas
import geopandas as gpd
```

So final solution :

```
!apt install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal
!apt install python3-rtree 
!pip install descartes
!pip install geopandas
import geopandas as gpd
```

Above mention piece of code work perfectly on my colab.